# Tibco-java Custom function error

Tags: java, tibco-designer

I created one custom java function in `TIBCO designer`. I loaded class file from my desktop. It was working fine. But, now I did some changes in that function and then created and loaded class file, but this time class file location is different(from clearcase). This cause an error where I used this function earlier and the error is :

> "No function in namespace:java://xyz"(xyz is class file name which I not changed).

Please help me to resolve this error without changing previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your package hierarchy in the Java file, if there is no change, looks like your Designer did not pick up the latest `.class` file from the new location.

**1.** Retry by completely closing your designer instances in your machine.

**2.** Reload by browsing the new .class file and save your project.

**3.** Check by validating this particular process only.

Hope you are out of this issue already.